# Cannot see keyframes in Graph editor but can see them in timeline

Tags: animation, graph-editor

[image]

I am going insane as I don't know what the reasoning is, I just wanted to make the last 2 keyfarmes have a different interlpolation than the one I had for the first few and i was trying to find it via graph editor but cannot seem to find the animation

Comment: That happens to me very often too , try : Click view , and disable Only keyframes from selected channels . Sometimes it works for me .

Comment: Maybe scroll down to a lower value than 40?

Comment: Try pressing the Home key while hovering over the Graph editor window.